# FacetWP show all Options and Facets

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

I´ve a question regarding FacetWP. My facets are linked to custom fields via checkboxes and dropdown.

Is it possible to show ALL options and facets even though there is no data as Ghosts?

For example:

I'e a Facet with Car Brands. Options are Audi, BMW, VW. I want to display VW option as ghost when no Post with VW is existing. Additionally empty checkboxes should shown to.

I want to display ALL options, empty and not empty.

I hope you could understand it.

Greetings Jan

Answer (score 1):

In your Facet settings is an option "Show Ghosts". Just use it :)

Cheers,
Patrick